# How to fix error message "__builtin_avr_delay_cycles expects a compile time integer constant make"?

Tags: c, adc

My program isn't being compiled using a GCC AVR compiler. It's a small game on a microprocessor and an LCD screen.

```
move_delay = 200;
_delay_ms( move_delay );
```

It doesn't like that this _delay_ms is a variable, but it needs to be a variable because I can adjust the screen action through an ADC. Is there a way I can make it a constant but still usable with the ADC?

Comment: Did you mean to say, "It doesn't look like this _delay_ms is a *function*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could roll you own by looping around the minimal delay you need as often as necessary to get the other delays you need.

```
void my_delay_ms(int ms)
{
  while (0 < ms)
  {  
    _delay_ms(1);
    --ms;
  }
}
```

This probably isn't 100% accurate due to time spend for calling `_delay_ms()` and decrementing `ms`. But for small ms it might be sufficient.

For larger values of `ms` you could introduce

```
void my_delay_ms_10ms_steps(int ms)
{
  while (0 < ms)
  {  
    _delay_ms(10);
    ms -= 10;
  }
}
```

and so on ...

---

Also a sort of dynamical approach is possible:

```
void mydyn_delay_ms(unsigned ms)
{
  unsigned i = 0;
  while (0 < ms)
  {
    if (0 != (ms % 2))
    {
      switch (i)
      {
        case 0:
           _delay_ms(1 << 0);
           break;

        case 1:
           _delay_ms(1 << 1);
           break;

        case 2:
           _delay_ms(1 << 2);
           break;

        /* and so on */

        case <what ever bit-width unsigned uses> -1:
          _delay_ms(1 << (<what ever bit-wdith unsigned uses> -1));
          break;
      }
    }

    ms >>= 1;
    ++i;
  }
}
```

**Update**:

Following up [*vaxquis* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422367/how-to-fix-error-message-builtin-avr-delay-cycles-expects-a-compile-time-inte/30423029#comment62814713_30423029) an alternative way to implement the functionality above would be:

```
void mydyn_delay_ms(unsigned ms)
{
  for (
    unsigned i = 0; /* requires at least C99 */
    0 < ms; 
    ++i)
  {
    if (0 != (ms % 2))
    {
      switch (i)
      {
        case 0:
           _delay_ms(1 << 0);
           break;

        case 1:
           _delay_ms(1 << 1);
           break;

        case 2:
           _delay_ms(1 << 2);
           break;

        /* and so on */

        case <what ever bit-width unsigned uses> -1:
          _delay_ms(1 << (<what ever bit-wdith unsigned uses> -1));
          break;
      }
    }

    ms >>= 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use the following define before the #include statement the delay functions can also be called with variables instead of numerical constants:

```
#define __DELAY_BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE__
#include <util/delay.h>

/************************************************************************
 * Function: sound
 * Description: Toggle Port to generate sound with a given pulse width.
 * Parameter: duration, pulsewidth
 * Uses: _delay_us()
 ************************************************************************/
void sound(uint16_t duration, uint16_t pulsewidth) {
  uint16_t i;
  uint16_t j = 2270 * duration/pulsewidth;

  for(i=0; i<j; i++) {
    SPKR_PORT |= (1 << SPKR_PAD);   //Set port -> create bit mask and OR it
    //delay
    _delay_us(pulsewidth);

    SPKR_PORT &= ~(1 << SPKR_PAD);   //clear port -> negate mask and AND it
    //delay
    _delay_us(pulsewidth);
  }
}
```