# How can I fix this. "__builtin_avr_delay_cycles expects a compile time integer constant"

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmel, servo

I'm using a **servo motor** with **atmega32A** MCU. I want to turn the motor by sending the degree to a function. Here is my main method.

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 8000000UL 
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "servo.h"

int main(void)
{
    DDRC = 0b00000001; 
    PORTC = 0x00;

    while(1)
    {
        turnTo(90);
    }
}
```

And this is my Servo motor code.

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 8000000UL // 8 MHz clock speed
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int turnTo(double degree){
    int pulse=(degree*500/90)+1000;
    PORTC = 0x01;

    _delay_us(pulse);

    PORTC = 0x00;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the below answers. But anything didn't work. How can I fix this?

[How to fix error message "__builtin_avr_delay_cycles expects a compile time integer constant make"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422367/how-to-fix-error-message-builtin-avr-delay-cycles-expects-a-compile-time-inte)

Comment: Please describe what you tried from that answer and how it "didn't work". Rolling your own loop is a good way to solve this problem. So if you tried it and it didn't work then you need to show exactly what you tried and explain what problems you got.

Comment: It's not a brilliant idea to use floating point on an old 8-bitter with no FPU. Because... it's not a PC.

Comment: Anyway, the answer you are looking for in on-chip hardware timers. Forget about using busy-delay loops, that's not how real-time systems are designed.

Comment: @kaylum  , I tried with that loop solution. It also not work. Showing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay function calculates the `no operation` loops during compile time and can not be dynamically on the controller. So try to add a function like this:

```c
void wait(unsigned int us)
{
  for(unsigned int i=0; i < us; i++)
  {
    _delay_us(1);
  }
}
```

and adapt your program

```c
int turnTo(double degree){
    unsigned int pulse=(degree*500/90)+1000;
    PORTC = 0x01;

    wait(pulse)

    PORTC = 0x00;
    
    return 0;
}
```

> It is not exactly cause the for loop also takes some assembler instructions. At the moment i have got no compiler to check but you can correct the result by counting the assembler instructions that the compiler uses and adapt `us` variable. A better solution is to use timer instead of delay. They have got a better accuracy as delay and the controller can do other things during counting!